# Can an external process view php exported variables?

Tags: php, environment-variables

If you use putenv in php to set the proxy for a web scraper, can other processes access that variable? How could you stop them doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, other processes can't access them.

```
php -r 'putenv("FOO=bar");'
echo $FOO
```